# How to develop web application after deployment in host?

Tags: php, laravel

recently I deployed my web application in host (hostinger.com), I have some edits I have to make. How can I use the code editor (PhpStorm) to make edit in the website ?

- the project made using laravel framework

Comment: Set up the application locally, make the changes you need using your favorite IDE, test it and make sure everything works and then upload the changed files to the server. Very straight forward.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Presumably you wrote code before deploying it to hostinger? Can't you do the same and just overwrite the old code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll not recommend, but in other-hand to gave you an answer, you should :

1. `View->Tool Window->Remote Host`
2. Create a new connection, base on connection type `FTP, SFTP, FTPS, Etc.`.
3. Set host info and try to connect.

As you can see this option don't need any type of `SSH` access, and when you've got connected to host, you can see list of files at right side of `IDE`, and you can :

- Browse
- Modify them
- And of-course change your files in local environment and put/upload or drag them into specified location.

Answer (score 0):

You will need SSH access to your remote files

In phpstorm:
File >> Remote Deployment...

Though it is generally better practice to make your changes locally, rebuild and redeploy to the host.

Comment: what if he only have an ftp access ?